# Problems when deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've been getting this very annoying app when I try to do anything with heroku... adding keys, deplying etc. I've looked at a lot of other posts, but it doesn't seem to be a problem for a lot of people, so I hoped you could help.

Here's what I get when I try to say `heroku keys:add`:

```
charlotte-dator:showwwdown holgersindbaek$ heroku keys:add
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: holgersindbaek@gmail.com 
Password: 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.9.0/lib/heroku/auth.rb:207:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Users/holgersindbaek/.heroku/credentials (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.9.0/lib/heroku/auth.rb:207:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.9.0/lib/heroku/auth.rb:207:in `write_credentials'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.9.0/lib/heroku/auth.rb:130:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.9.0/lib/heroku/auth.rb:71:in `get_credentials'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.9.0/lib/heroku/command/keys.rb:40:in `add'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.9.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:114:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.9.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:114:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.9.0/bin/heroku:14
    from /usr/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:19
```

Really hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: What does `ls -al /Users/holgersindbaek/.heroku/` tell you?

Comment: It tells me permission denied!

Comment: It works when you do sudo heroku "whatever", but I shouldn't have to do that, should I?

Comment: Did you install the heroku gem as su? If so, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo mkdir /Users/holgersindbaek/.heroku
sudo chown -R holgersindbaek /Users/holgersindbaek/.heroku
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks!
I'm getting some new problems though. When i do a heroku db:migrate, Heroku needs the "gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter" to be able to convert my mysql database. So I put that in my gemfile and try to run bundle install, but then it tells me: /Users/holgersindbaek/Projekter/Showwwdown/showwwdown/Gemfile:34:in `evaluate': undefined local variable or method `activerecord' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0x10179a228> (NameError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build' + some more errors. Any idea why this is? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure on that one.  Sorry.  Maybe ask in a different question here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Heroku website it says to install:

```
$gem install taps
```